# Huge White Field in Footer on Specific Device

Tags: css, wordpress, themes, footer

It's not visible everywhere, just on some devices. Literally a huge white field below footer. Another person has shown it to me, it's not visible even on my PC.

Here's a visualisation of what I am talking about: nikosis.mzonespace.co.uk/108.jpg

Here's a CSS code:

```css
  Footer
//=======================================================================*/
#footer {
    position: relative;
}
#footer .widget{
    margin: 0;
}
#footer .ft-bg{
    background: url("../images/icons/bg-slider-matt-1.png") repeat-x top center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    -ms-transform: rotate(180deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
#footer .ft-bg.style2{
    background: url("../images/icons/bg-footer-style2.png") repeat;
    top: 100px;
    bottom: 80px;
    opacity: 0.2;
}
#footer .ft-img{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#footer .ft-img img{
    width: 100%;
    max-width: none;
    height: auto;
}
#footer a{
 color:#efefef;
}
#footer h3 span{
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #464646;
}
#footer-wrapper{
    color: #464646;;
 padding:163px 0 0;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1170px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 400;
    position: relative;
}
.footer-top{
    background:url("../images/icons/bg-dot.jpg") repeat-x ;
    /*margin-bottom: 150px;*/
}
.style2 .footer-top{
    background:none;
    /*padding-top:74px;*/
}
.footer-top .span4{
    padding-right: 120px;
}
.footer-top .span4:last-child{
    padding-right: 0;
}
.footer-bottom{
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 300;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    padding-top: 25px;
}
.style2 .footer-bottom{
    color: #464646;
    padding-top: 50px;
}
.footer-bottom .span6:last-child{
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 15px;
}
#copyright-wrapper {
 font-size:12px;
 padding: 15px 0;
 background-color:#fff;
}
#copyright-wrapper [class*="span"]{
 min-height:1px;
}
#copyright-wrapper #secondary-nav ul{
 margin:0;
}
#copyright-wrapper #secondary-nav ul li{
 line-height:100%;
 padding:0 10px;
 border-left:1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}
#copyright-wrapper #secondary-nav ul li:first-child{
 border:none;
}
.scrollTop{
 position:fixed;
    bottom: 55px;
 right:15px;
 display:none;
}
.scrollTop a{
 text-indent:-9999px;
 background: #d3d3d9 url(../images/icons/scroll-top.png) no-repeat center;
 width:40px;
 height:40px;
 display:block;
}
/*=========================================================================
```

Here's the page: nikosis.mzonespace.co.uk/blog-full-layout/

Comment: Can you tell us on what devices it does and doesn't work on as an edit of your question?

Comment: As stated in my comment you should add that in an edit of your question, posting it as an answer will just have it deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that after the layout collapses for mobile/tablet, the white area appears. The corresponding CSS is called #footer-wrapper.

```
     #footer-wrapper: padding-top:400px;
```

It should be in a file called responsive.css .. I have removed the padding and the white area disappeared. Also, the footer-wrapper contains some test1 and test2. I don't see any codes or other content loaded in it. So, you might as well remove it from your code. Or even set it to display:none in case you don't know where is it. However, since you are on wordpress, it could be in your template files in footer.php or something similar.

Hope this helps!